# EXTJS 4.2 and grid header color

Tags: css, extjs

I can't find a way to display grid header (but not simple header) in defined by me: font and background color. 
Situation is the following:
 - I have a grid with columns like this:

```
  -----------------------------------------
    |               name                |
  --|-----------------------------------|--
    |      part 1     |      part 2     |
  --|-----------------------------------|--
    |  p1 |  p2 |  p3 |  p1 |  p2 |  p3 |
  --|-----------------------------------|--
```

- I have to display ONLY main header field
   ("name") in special color on special background,
   let's say white on red
- in main column ("name") definition I set
      style: (for font color)
      cls:   (for defined in css file, background color)

And I can set font color for every "level" of headers 
differently as I want, but background color anyway
working for all of the headers.

Be so kind and tell me why?:

Comment: Please make a fiddle showing what you do now. I can search for an example tomorrow where I have changed the color of only some of the headers.

Comment: Damn, SORRY - it's ExtJS 4.2, not 5!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the framework draws the headers of the grid as nested div's and subheaders has transparent background, and hence take the background of the parent element (as opposed to the HTML table in which such a grouping is done by colspan property and each header is separate td / th element).

I can offer two solutions for this task:

1. Add `cls` to your column

   ```
   {
       text: 'Contact Info',
       cls: 'customGridHeader',
       columns: [
           {
               text: 'Email',
               dataIndex: 'email'
           },
           {
               text: 'Phone',
               dataIndex: 'phone'
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

   and via css direct child selector add required styles for column inner div

   ```
   .customGridHeader > .x-column-header-inner {
       background: red;
       color: white;
   }
   ```

   [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bbztj6u/)
2. Add color to the table header via `styles`, but you have to add colors to             the subheaders aswell (you can use `defaults` attribture to apply style for all child components)

   [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/113t)

Comment: Thank you very much Sergey but it's my mistake (in the header :-)). I use ExtJS 4.2 for this project not ExtJS 5!

Comment: Actually it doesnt metter, style for certain column should work in 4.2 without changes.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov Thanks for preparing a fiddle, which the questioner seems unable to do. You did not get it quite right; he should have done it himself, so you can see the issue he has. I have [forked your fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1142) to show you the problem Tad has: The main header is white on red, which is correct; but the lower headers are dark gray on red (should be dark gray on light gray). His question is whether there is any solution apart from the obvious one (using the "style" attribute to revert the background on each child column, which is unmaintainable).

Comment: @Alexander Ah, I see. Well, yes playing with style doesnt sole TS problem. As dirty solution we can use defaults to revert styles.

Comment: Practice - when I set "style" to all headers fields (part 1, part 2 and p1, p2, ...) of level 2 and 3 situation is the same. All fields background color is red. I have only one column with such a set (I mean header text displayed white on red), the rest of columns are displayed proper. Additionally when I set background color as NAVY to "part1, part2, p1, p2, ... all the rest columns headers are display their headers with navy background color. So?

Comment: And look on the fiddle please. I modified style for one column, 'Name' (yellow on brown) and in ExtJS 5.0.1.1255 Neptune it's working properly but (my version) in ExtJS 4.2.1.833 Neptune it's not working at all.

Comment: I updead my answer, check solution 1, i guess it is what you want.

Comment: No it's not working. I tried it before and it work for font color but not for background. I use style for "part ..." and "p ..." level of column header, exactly as yours (white on blue) and in all headers, but no in this "white-on-red", I have white text on blue background. But in this special column header text is WHITE but background is still RED. It looks like style on "name" level is "harder" then default styles on lower levels. Same situation is when I set style, not as default to every column.

Comment: But, maybe problem is, that I set this colors for "white-on-red" header not by "style", but by "cls" property. I define in css!

Comment: I do not understand what difference between my solution 1 fiddle and your problem. Can you, please, leave a link to your code using http://paste2.org/, and I will prepare a working fiddle with it.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. When I manipulate with background color with 'cls' problem exists but when I use 'style' in place of 'cls' it's working as you said. 
Thanks. 

And I try to change your fiddle to show it.